# Is is ok to call Array#pop inside Array#each?

Tags: ruby

I want to remove unnecessary `Hash` from a end of `Array` like a `String#strip`, so I wrote like this:

```
a = [{date: Date.today, foo: nil},
     {date: Date.today - 1, foo: 1},
     {date: Date.today - 2, foo: 8},
     {date: Date.today - 3, foo: nil},
     {date: Date.today - 4, foo: nil},
     {date: Date.today - 5, foo: 7},     
     {date: Date.today - 6, foo: nil}     
    ]

a.reverse.each do |v|
  v[:foo].nil? ? a.pop : break
end
```

This code works fine as I expected.

```
=> [{:date=>Tue, 24 Feb 2015, :foo=>nil},
 {:date=>Mon, 23 Feb 2015, :foo=>1},
 {:date=>Sun, 22 Feb 2015, :foo=>8},
 {:date=>Sat, 21 Feb 2015, :foo=>nil},
 {:date=>Fri, 20 Feb 2015, :foo=>nil},
 {:date=>Thu, 19 Feb 2015, :foo=>7}]
```

But is it ok to call `Array#pop` in `Enumerable#each`?
I feel it is unsafe to change the array itself inside a loop.

Comment: unsafe, how? Although not particularly elegant, if it get's the job done ... I don't see any safety problem with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Matz [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-core-google/wYAJdScsv9w), it is undefined behaviour to modify a collection that is being iterated.

Instead try something like this:

```
while ! array.last[:foo]
  array.pop
end
```